# Requested ChangeOrientation operation for ‘Pdf’ document type is not supported groupdocs merger

Tags: orientation, groupdocs

I am creating a web application and I am using groupdocs for view pdf and other docs,
in one of the scenario I want to change particular page orientation of pdf document, I found groupdocs merger with a set of code [from here](https://docs.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/flip-or-rotate-pages/) and I modified that code with my expectations which is below,

```
string filePath = @"c:\sample.pdf";

OrientationOptions orientationOptions = new OrientationOptions(OrientationMode.Landscape, new int[] { 3, 4 });

using (Merger merger = new Merger(filePath))
{
    merger.ChangeOrientation(orientationOptions);
    merger.Save(filePath);
}
```

but I am getting the below error

> Requested ChangeOrientation operation for ‘Pdf’ document type is not
> supported

I tried this in groupdocs 21.8 version

Answer (score 0):

> I found groupdocs merger with a set of code [from here](https://docs.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/flip-or-rotate-pages/)

We cannot reproduce this issue using GroupDocs.Viewer for .NET [rotate pages](https://docs.groupdocs.com/viewer/net/flip-or-rotate-pages/). Have a look at the blow screenshot and the code:

[image]

```
using (Viewer viewer = new Viewer(@"D:/test.pdf"))
 {
     PdfViewOptions viewOptions = new PdfViewOptions(@"D:/output.pdf");
     viewOptions.RotatePage(1, Rotation.On90Degree); 
     viewer.View(viewOptions);
 }
```

As you are using GroupDocs Viewer API to render/view documents. Please use the above mentioned code. However, this issue exists in GroupDocs.Merger for .NET and we are working on the fix.

Comment: As far as rotating pages in GroupDocs.Merger for .NET is concerned, please use [this](https://docs.groupdocs.com/merger/net/rotate-pages/) code.